# doctrine 2 / symfony 2 - FindBy in similar tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, relationship, entities

Many thanks for your time, to help the community.

We are working in a project to manage orders with differents type of products, and need stablish a relationship between they.

```
class product{
    protected $order;
    protected $price;
    //Another global methods and parameters
}

class train extends product{
    protected $departureStation;
    protected $arrivalStation;
    //specific methods and parameters
}

class hotel extends product{
    protected $address;
}
```

How can I search for all products in a order, without call in every entity?

It's possible that store in order class a reference to the differents products, for example:

```
class order{
    protected $products;
    public function addProduct($product)
    {
        //This "product" are differents entities with the same extendend entity.
        $this->products[] = $product;
    }
}
```

How can i define the relationship between entities?

Many Thanks

Comment: Event if you extend `Product`, in fact, you have 3 entities `Hotel`, `Train` and `Product`. If you want to get all of them in `Order`, you have to declare them with a relation OneToMany Order side and ManyToOne to their side. Something like `protected $products;`, `protected $hotels;` and `protected $trains;` It's too long to write but try if you face an issue I could help

Comment: Thanks, I think in use this form but we have more that 50 different type of products. (train, boat, bus, hotel, house, etc...) and need any other method more dinamyc

Comment: So you should rethink your entity `Product`. Instead of extending it, you should add a field `Type`. Then you create `Class Type` with required method if it's by train, boat ... That way, you'll have only one Product with différent type of shipping/transporting. My two cents...

Comment: But if we use Forms where save the data? I'm think that can put the additional data in a other entity related to each product `class params{ protected $idproducto; protected $name; protected $value;}` but if i need make operations with this value, how it's possible? Thanks!

Comment: That can be also a possibility if you create `OneToOne` relation between each Product and its Params. Doctrine will automatically set the product id and will manage the relation for you. So before persisting your Product, you can also populate its params. To get `Params`, you could use something like `$product->getParams()`. Anyway, I think extending your product is not the best way to go here.